# Python: query performance on JSON vs sqlite?

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I have a JSON file that has the following format:

```
{
  "items": {
     "item_1_name": { ...item properties... }
     "item_2_name": { ...item properties... }
     ...
  }
}
```

On my last count, there can be over 13K items stored in the JSON file, and the file itself is nearly 75MB on disk.

Now, I have a program that needs to query (read-only) data. Each query operation takes an item name and needs to read its properties. Each invocation of that program may involve from a few to several dozen query ops.

Naturally, loading the JSON file from disk and parsing it takes time and space: it takes 0.76 seconds to load and parse, and the parsed data takes 197 MB in memory. That means on each invocation of that program, I need to first wait nearly a second before it can do anything else with the results. I want to make the program respond faster.

So I have another approach: create a SQLite database file from that JSON file. Afterwards, the program needs to query against the database, instead of querying against the data directly parsed from the JSON file.

However, the SQLite approach has one drawback: unlike json.load(), it doesn't parse the whole file and keep it around in memory (assuming cache miss), and I'm not sure if the time spent on disk IO encountered by the query ops may offset the benefit of not using the JSON approach.

So my question is: from your experience, is this use case suitable for SQLite?

Comment: When I had to do something like that, though with XML, not JSON, I did create an SQLite DB. The rationale is that in order to perform just a few queries on the data, you need to read a far smaller proportion of the SQLite DB than you would need for reading an entire JSON/XML. I did not compare performance, but what I got using SQLite was satisfactory.

Comment: sqlite is a database, and what you describe sounds exactly like what a database is used for... but the only real answer for your particular use-case would be to actually profile it. I would note, aside from the overhead of parsing the JSON into the nested dict, you aren't going to get much faster than a couple hash lookups. But again, you need to check and see.

Comment: It depends on your use case. Are there any limitations using a real database (mysql, postgres, 'in memory database' like redis) that's what they are made for. What about PyPy i assume that would be way faster than cpython.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer It's just a commandline productivity utility, not something meant to run as a service, so I'd like it to take as few dependencies as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this depends *entirely* on how you're querying the data. From the way you describe it, you're querying by an ID only, so you're not going to get the best of what sqlite has to offer by way of efficiencies. It should work just fine for your use case, but it would excel at returning all records matching a value, all record with values between two integers, etc. A third option worth considering is a minimal key/value store such as a python dictionary stored as a `pickle` or a really simple `redis` service. Both of these will allow to query by ID faster than reading a large json string.